# How do I put an unsubscribe link on the email next to sender name?

Tags: html, email, url

I saw this link in one of my emails.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHkzJ.png)

How do I format my email (html or url) in such a way to have this effect? Is there also a way to format my email to have a "subscribe" button?

Comment: Please read how to ask a question in the help section

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.adweek.com/digital/gmails-unsubscribe-button-could-be-huge-blow-email-marketers-159354/) link. Gmail (and some other email providers) now check the email for an unsubscribe link and automatically copy it to the email header.

There is as far as I'm aware no way of doing this to subscribe to an email.

So to achieve this just include an unsubscribe link as you would normally.